# C: How to read values from scanf until a given value is read

Tags: c

I am trying to write a program that gets a sequence of int values from the user, and stores them in order to calculate some statistics afterwards. When the user types 0, the sequence ends. 
For example: 5965 68 42 -45 0

So far I have this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

int number;

do {
scanf("%d", &number);
}
while (number != 0);

return number;

}
```

This code doesn't work, as no values are being saved. I think I should be storing the values in an array, but how can I do that without giving an array its size?

Have in mind I am a complete beginner to C programming.

Comment: You could program your own vector (dynamic array) with a linked list.

Comment: If you don't know anything of C programming, answering you in a manner you will find useful is near impossible without writing your program for you (and we don't do that here). As to _How to read values from scanf until a given value is read_ - your program already does that (with the problem @Olaf points out below). You might find that thinking about the problem long enough to communicate it clearly can help you to solve it on your own (but if you're a complete beginner in C, that might not be the case here as the concepts you need for dynamic sizing are a bit advanced).

Comment: Your code invokes undefined behaviour if the first iteration does not read valid data. **Always** check the result of `scanf` and other functions which may encounter a critical error.

Comment: `number` is a scalar, and therefore can hold only one value at a time. In this case, you will get 0 stored in it, as that is the most recent value scanned before your `while` loop terminates. You do need an array, but it doesn't have to be dynamic; it just need to be big enough to hold the maximum count of numbers that you will enter.

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: All the code below are untested and may contain bugs as I've written them using my phone.

---

One way would be to declare a large enough array and store the inputs on by one:

```
int array[100], number, i;

puts("Enter the numbers (max 100):");
for(i = 0; i < 100 && scanf("%d", &number) == 1 && number != 0; i++)
{
    array[i] = number;
}

puts("You entered:");
for(int j = 0; j < i; j++)
{
    printf("array[%d] = %d\n", j, array[j]);
}
```

Another way would be to ask the user for the maximum number of elements and create an array of that size.

For this, there are two ways:

1. If you use C99+, you can use a VLA:

   ```
   int number, i;

   printf("Enter the number of elements: ");
   for(;;)
   {
       int r = scanf("%d", &number);
       if(r == 1 && number > 0)
       {
           break;
       }
       else if(r == 0 || number <= 0)
       {
           fputs("Invalid input. Try again", stderr);
           scanf("%*s");
       }
       else
       {
           fputs("EOF detected; Bailing out!", stderr);
           exit(-1)
       }
   }

   int array[number], temp; /* VLA */

   for(i = 0; i < number && scanf("%d", &temp) == 1 && temp != 0; i++)
   {
       array[i] = temp;
   }

   puts("You entered:");
   for(int j = 0; j < i; j++)
   {
       printf("array[%d] = %d\n", j, array[j]);
   }
   ```
2. Otherwise, use dynamic memory allocation:

   ```
   int number, i;

   printf("Enter the number of elements: ");
   for(;;)
   {
       int r = scanf("%d", &number);
       if(r == 1 && number > 0)
       {
           break;
       }
       else if(r == 0 || number <= 0)
       {
           fputs("Invalid input. Try again", stderr);
           scanf("%*s");
       }
       else
       {
           fputs("EOF detected; Bailing out!", stderr);
           exit(-1)
       }
   }

   if(SIZE_MAX / sizeof(int) < number)
   {
       fputs("Too large size, will overflow; Bailing out", stderr);
       exit(-2);
   }

   int* array = malloc(number * sizeof(int)), temp; /* Dynamic memory allocation via malloc */
   if(!array)
   {
       fputs("malloc failed!", stderr);
       exit(-3);
   }

   for(i = 0; i < number && scanf("%d", &temp) == 1 && temp != 0; i++)
   {
       array[i] = temp;
   }

   puts("You entered:");
   for(int j = 0; j < i; j++)
   {
       printf("array[%d] = %d\n", j, array[j]);
   }

   free(array);
   ```

The third way would be to `malloc` a small chunk of memory and then increase it gradually as required, using `realloc` until the end.

Note: Functions `malloc`, `realloc`, `exit` requires `stdlib.h` to be included and the macro `SIZE_MAX` requires `stdint.h`.

Comment: your malloc call can have a overflow and alloc only a few bytes while number is still very high (may be 0x40000003 would alloc only 12 bytes in case int is 4 bytes), and the user can enter a shellcode. you should check for a overflow first.

Comment: use: if(SIZE_MAX/sizeof(int)<number){/*int overflow*/} before you do number*sizeof(int)

Comment: Wait, You said that "_0x40000003 would alloc only 12 bytes in case int is 4 bytes_", but wouldn't the expression `0x40000003 * 4`  be automatically converted into `size_t` since `sizeof(int)` returns a `size_t` and the correct size is allocated?

Comment: ok int is signed, and size_t unsigned, so it would may result in a long long int, and long long can store the result, but if size_t is only 32 bit, it would by 12 passed to malloc (0x10000000C & 0xFFFFFFFF). So sorry, it is important the maximum size_t, not of of int.

Comment: Ok. I edited my answer. I hope it looks good now. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

in order to do what you wish we'll have to use dynamic memory allocation (to be sure that it will work regardless). So here we go:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#define INCR_SIZE 32
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

  int *numbers = NULL , *tmp = NULL , sz=0 , cnt=0;

  while(1){    

    if(cnt >= sz) {
      tmp = realloc(numbers,(sz+=INCR_SIZE)*sizeof(int));
      if(!tmp) {
    //memory allocation failed
    //should use exit(1) to prevent accessing unallocated memory
      }
      else
    numbers = tmp;
    }
    if(scanf("%d", &numbers[cnt])!=1) {
      //could not read a number
      break;
    }
    if(!numbers[cnt]) // if a 0 is read, break
      break;
    cnt++;
  }

  for(int i=0 ; i < cnt ; ++i)
    printf("%d ",numbers[i]);
  putchar('\n');
  return 0;
}
```